Shared memory in parallel foreach using set.seed
As seen in this question, in Windows it is not possible to run parallel processes with shared memory in R. Therefore, I have devised the following methodology, using a series of set.seed(), to simulate a "shared memory" between my cores.
First, I want to simulate a random variable (RV) matrix:

The lines represent the fixed number of loans.
The columns represent the number of Monte Calro simulations.

Second, I want to repeat the above a certain number of times, precisely nruns times. At each run in the nruns any metric (mean, quantile) can be computed from this matrix.
nruns <- 4
nsim.runs <- c(5000, 10000)
nport.total <- 10
n.sectors <- 2
K <- n.sectors

ISCorrMatrix <- matrix(data=0.5, nrow=n.sectors, ncol=n.sectors, byrow=TRUE)
diag(ISCorrMatrix) <- 1

Alpha.Matrix <- t(chol(ISCorrMatrix))

Alpha.Matrix.extended <- NULL

for (i in 1:n.sectors) {
  new <- matrix(data=Alpha.Matrix[i, ], nrow=nport.total/2, ncol=n.sectors, 
                byrow=TRUE)
  Alpha.Matrix.extended <- rbind(Alpha.Matrix.extended, new)
}

beta.star <- runif(n.sectors, min=0.1, max=0.9)  ## so just draw them at random.
beta.star <- beta.star/sqrt(sum(beta.star^2))  ## to normalise the draw.

sum(beta.star^2)

## Initialize parallel backend
num_cores <- length(nsim.runs)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## Set up a reproducible RNG stream
clusterSetRNGStream(cl)

parallel_results <- foreach(core=1:length(nsim.runs), .combine="c") %dopar% {
  nsim <- nsim.runs[core]
  results <- list()
  set.seed(123)
  for (run in 1:nruns) { 
    Z.systematic <- matrix(data=rnorm(nsim*K), nrow=K, ncol=nsim, byrow=FALSE)
    Y.systematic <- Alpha.Matrix %*% Z.systematic
    Y.systematic.star <- beta.star %*% Z.systematic
    Y.systematic.extended <- c()
    for (i in 1:n.sectors) {
      new <- matrix(data=rep(Y.systematic[i, ], nport.total/2), 
                    nrow=nport.total/2, ncol=nsim, byrow=TRUE)
      Y.systematic.extended <- rbind(Y.systematic.extended, new)
    }
    Y.systematic.extended.star <- 
      matrix(data=Y.systematic.star, nrow=nport.total, ncol=nsim, byrow=TRUE)
    set.seed(123 + run*100000) 
    Z.Default <- matrix(data=rnorm(nsim*nport.total), nrow=nport.total,
                        ncol=nsim, byrow=FALSE) 
    set.seed(123 + run*100000)
    LGD.Basel <- matrix(data=rbeta(n=nsim*nport.total, shape1=2, shape2=3),
                        nrow=nport.total, ncol=nsim, byrow=FALSE)
    results[[paste0("run_", run, "_Nsim_", nsim)]] <- 
      list(Y.systematic=Y.systematic.extended.star, 
           Z.Default=Z.Default, 
           LGD=LGD.Basel)
  }
  return(results)  ## The return call of the parallelisation.
}

## Stop the parallel backend
stopCluster(cl)

If we focus on one run across the cores, I want that:

The first core simulates 5000 columns (Monte Carlo simulations).
The second core simulates 10000 columns (Monte Carlo simulations). To avoid simulation noise, the first 5000 columns shall contain the same simulated RV as in the first core, and so on, as more cores are added to the parallelisation.

This methodology aims to replicate a situation in which you first simulated a large matrix of 10000 Monte Carlo simulations, and then assigned the first 5000 columns to the first core, the full 10000 columns to the second core, and so on (if there are more simulations).
If we focus on multiple run(s) across the same core, I want that if I rerun its nsim, to get a newly generated random matrix, independent of the one generated in the previous run, and so on.
Visually, when the above methodology is applied to compute one quantile, per run, across a series of cores each having a different number of nsim this yields:

My code seems to achieve that (here I show only Y and Z, but also works for the LGD):
Stability for same run across nsims: Y
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_5000$Y.systematic[1:2,4998:5000]
           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.2397531 1.548914 0.2781637
[2,] -0.2397531 1.548914 0.2781637
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_10000$Y.systematic[1:2,4998:5002]
           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]    [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.2397531 1.548914 0.2781637 2.23994 -0.6209843
[2,] -0.2397531 1.548914 0.2781637 2.23994 -0.6209843

Variability for different runs across same nsim: Y
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_5000$Y.systematic[1:2,1:2]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.3996827 0.2019272
[2,] -0.3996827 0.2019272
> parallel_results$run_2_Nsim_5000$Y.systematic[1:2,1:2]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.4580132 -0.08322681
[2,] -0.4580132 -0.08322681

Stability for same run across nsims: Z
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_5000$Z.Default[1:2,4998:5000]
          [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.077092 -0.006225626 -0.6152041
[2,]  2.033250 -1.350659878 -0.7040274
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_10000$Z.Default[1:2,4998:5002]
          [,1]         [,2]       [,3]        [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -1.077092 -0.006225626 -0.6152041  0.57472772  2.593232
[2,]  2.033250 -1.350659878 -0.7040274 -0.08696669 -1.456689

Variability for different runs across same nsim: Z
> parallel_results$run_1_Nsim_5000$Z.Default[1:2,1:2]
              [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.0008058532 -1.0539683
[2,] -1.3029004815 -0.2031874
> parallel_results$run_2_Nsim_5000$Z.Default[1:2,1:2]
            [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.50913790 -1.120769
[2,] -0.03775884  0.894895

Question:
My question is now, are the nruns draws in the same core truly independent (I have checked the summary stats and the corr, they seem to be...)? Or have I inserted some undesired link through the set.seed() setting?
Are there considerations linked to the RNG in R (and its interaction with the parallel package) I have missed? I have extensively searched across stack but was unable to find something matching my application.

FYI the absence of memory sharing between processes isn’t limited to Windows. It’s the same in every modern operating system. And R in fact relies on this fact.

Konrad Rudolph: Thank you very much for your input. Is then the seed advancement I have devised insuring that the draws in each nrun (set.seed(123 + run*100000)) are iid ? I have used 100000 to space the seed seeting, while controlling it. Is there another way to proceed ?

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you're doing something like this,
> library(doParallel)
> cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
> registerDoParallel(cl)
> 
> foreach(core=1:3, .combine="list") %dopar% {
+   rn <- array(, c(2, 2))
+   for (run in seq_len(nrow(rn))) {
+     set.seed(41 + run)
+     rn[, run] <- rnorm(2)
+   }
+   rn
+ }
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.03751376
[2,] -0.5646982 -1.57460441

[[1]][[2]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.03751376
[2,] -0.5646982 -1.57460441


[[2]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.03751376
[2,] -0.5646982 -1.57460441

which yields similar values. If that's not your intention, you might want to add the iteration i to the seed, though it's not ideal since random seeds in general are actually pseudo-random.
> 
> stopCluster(cl)
> 
> library(parallel)
> cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
> 
> parLapply(cl, 1:3, \(i) {
+   rn <- array(, c(2, 2))
+   for (run in seq_len(nrow(rn))) {
+     set.seed(41 + run + i)
+     rn[, run] <- rnorm(2)
+   }
+   rn
+ })
[[1]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.03751376 0.65391826
[2,] -1.57460441 0.01905227

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.65391826  0.3407997
[2,] 0.01905227 -0.7033403

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.3407997 -0.8989165
[2,] -0.7033403  0.2121311

> 
> stopCluster(cl)


jay.sf: Thanks a lot for your answer and suggestions, I have increased the clarity of my question (I hope). Your explanation is useful, but is not exactly helping me understand if my draws generated within one core for multiple runs are truly independent. Especially, when the nport.total size grows to, say, 10,000 and the nsim  to 500,000.

First, generate random seeds for all streams that you will use and then explicitly use them in your simulation to manage the streams.
nsim.runs <- c(5, 10, 15, 20)
num_cores <- 3

library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(123)
s <- vector("list", length(nsim.runs))
s[[1]] <- .Random.seed
for(i in seq_along(s)[-1]) {
  s[[i]] <- nextRNGStream(s[[i - 1]])
}

foreach(run = seq_along(nsim.runs)) %dopar% {
  rn <- matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = run)
  for (r in seq_len(run)) {
    assign(".Random.seed", s[[r]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
    rn[, r] <- rnorm(5)
  }

rn
}

stopCluster(cl)

Output:
[[1]]
           [,1]
[1,] -0.9685927
[2,]  0.7061091
[3,]  1.4890213
[4,] -1.8150926
[5,]  0.3304096

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.9685927 -0.4094454
[2,]  0.7061091  0.8909694
[3,]  1.4890213 -0.8653704
[4,] -1.8150926  1.4642711
[5,]  0.3304096  1.2674845

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.9685927 -0.4094454 -0.48906078
[2,]  0.7061091  0.8909694  0.43304237
[3,]  1.4890213 -0.8653704 -0.03195349
[4,] -1.8150926  1.4642711  0.14670372
[5,]  0.3304096  1.2674845 -1.75239095

[[4]]
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.9685927 -0.4094454 -0.48906078 -1.0388664
[2,]  0.7061091  0.8909694  0.43304237  1.5745125
[3,]  1.4890213 -0.8653704 -0.03195349  0.7470820
[4,] -1.8150926  1.4642711  0.14670372  0.6718720
[5,]  0.3304096  1.2674845 -1.75239095  0.2691436


The .Random.seed variable used by the generators is in the global environment, so it is important to set it there. Setting it just inside a function may not be effective. The variable contains the RNG type as well as its current seed.
The streams are guaranteed to be independent and because you have access to all streams (via their .Random.seed) on all cores, you can manage which portions of matrices are generated by which streams.
If you need to manage the continuation of the various streams, you can reassign .Random.seed to return to a previous position. Just remember to do it in the global environment.
A detailed explanation of parallel RNG is given in the parallel package vignette.

George Ostrouchov: Thank you very much for your answer and insightful input, I am testing your solution right now. Small typo: I believe you just forgot a parenthesis closing the for loop. Thanks again !

rge Ostrouchov: Starting from your example, I have tried:
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG") set.seed(123)  # Initialize seed seeds <- vector("list", nruns) for(i in 1:nruns) {   seeds[[i]] <- .Random.seed  # Capture current RNG state   .Random.seed <- nextRNGStream(.Random.seed)  # Update the RNG state to the next stream } seeds
And, keeping the first, set.seed(123), replace my subsequent set.seed(123 + run*100000) by  .Random.seed <- seeds[[run]].

Indeed, my end goal is just to replace my manual change of the set.seed, for each run, in a way that guarantees that the draws are iid. Unfortunately, the above does not work. Could you elaborate more on your input ?

I've expanded the code. The output columns are independent streams, each associated with one nsim.runs vector element. Let me know if this is what you are looking for and I will update the comments

George Ostrouchov: Thank you very much for your input ! It is getting much clearer now :) First question: I have run the first part of your code, when I open s, I see that all the "seeds" in the list seem identical... while your code indeed controls a different draw at each rnorm call, why is so ? Second question: I see why you call .Random.seed <- s[[r]] before the rnorm call, but why do you need to do s[[r]] <- .Random.seed  after the execution or rnorm ?

I forgot to set things in the global environment so it was not doing what i thought. I updated the code and the comments to reflect the correct understanding. Thanks for catching that seeds were identical earlier!

I should add that I have answered your situation stated with "If we focus on one run across the cores, ..." but I do not understand your bigger picture. I suspect that your set.seed() lines do not guarantee that your streams are independent and should be explicitly managed with a setting similar to what I describe.
